# Summable Function Equivalent to Zero

Tags: measure-theory

Let $f$ be a summable function on $[a, b]$ and there exists a constant $c$ such that $0<c<b-a$ and for any measurable subset $E$ of $[a, b]$ of measure $c$ we have $$\int_Ef(x)dx = 0,$$ then prove that $f$ is equivalent to $0$ on $[a, b]$

Consider the sets $$E_0 = (x : f(x) \neq 0),$$ $$E_1 = (x : f(x) > 0),$$ $$E_2 = (x : f(x) < 0).$$ Now let $f$ is not equivalent to $0$ on $[a, b]$. Hence at least one of the sets $E_1$ or $E_2$ has positive measure so WLOG let us assume that $mE_1 > 0$. If $c < \frac{b-a}{2}$ then either $mE_1 + mE_0^c \geq c$ or $mE_2 + mE_0^c \geq c$, because if both the inequalities are false then we have $$mE_1 + mE_2 + 2mE_0^c < 2c < b-a \implies b-a + mE_0^c < b-a,$$ a contradiction.

Now WLOG let us assume that the first inequality is true then we have $mE_0^c \geq c-mE_1$ and hence we can find a subset $e'$ of $E_0^c$ such that $me' = c-mE_1$.
Now consider the set $e' \cup E_1$. On this set we have $f(x) \geq 0$ and $m(e' \cup E_1)=c$ and so $$\int_{e' \cup E_1}f(x)dx=0 \implies \int_{e'}f(x)dx + \int_{E_1}f(x)dx = 0 \implies \int_{E_1}f(x)dx = 0,$$ a contradiction as on the set $E_1$, $f(x) > 0$ and $mE_1 > 0$.

Now for the case when $c \geq \frac{b-a}{2}$ i do not know how to proceed.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First, it is easy to show that if $f$ has a constant sign we have a contradiction.

Let $E^+=\lbrace x \,| f(x)\geq 0 \rbrace$ and $E^-=\lbrace x \,| f(x)\leq 0 \rbrace$.

If either $E^+$ or $E^-$ have measure larger than $c$ you can apply your reasoning.

Since $m(E^+)<c$, there exists a subset A of $E_2$ of measure $c-m(E^+)$ such that $\int_{E^+ \cup A} f=0$. And therefore $\int_{[a,b]} f= \int_{E_2 \backslash A} f <0$.

Now we can apply the same reasoning for $E^-$, showing that $\int_{[a,b]} f>0$. Hence the contradiction.